# Database development and deployment methods and tools

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, deployment, version-control

My team develop a web application using ASP.NET. The application is very much based on database (We use SQL Server). Most features require database development, in addition to server and client side code. We use GIT as our source code management system.

In order to check in (and later deploy) the database changes, we create SQL scripts and check them in. Our installer knows to run them and this is how we deploy these changes. Using scripts is very uncomfortable to merge changes (for example, if two developers added a column to the same table).

So my question is what other method or tool can you suggest? I know Visual Studio has a database project which may be useful, I still haven't learned about it, I wonder if there are other options out there before I start learning about it.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an easy way to deploy database changes using SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948220/what-is-an-easy-way-to-deploy-database-changes-using-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you have to add in worlflow and use [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) from the first steps of database development (check [Liquibase Quick-Start](http://www.liquibase.org/quickstart), where changelog started from creating initial structures).

From developers POV adding Liquibase means [appearing of additional XML-file(s) in source-tree](http://www.liquibase.org/bestpractices), when database-schema have to be changed in some changeset

Answer (score 0):

First full disclosure that I work for Red Gate who make this product...

You might be interested in taking a look at [SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/).  It's a plugin for SSMS that connects your development database to your existing version control system, git in your case.

When a developer makes a change to a dev database (either in a dedicated local copy, or in a shared dev database) then this change is detected and can then be committed to the repository.  Other developers can pick up this change, and you can propagate it up to other environments.

When it comes to deployment you can then use the SQL Compare tool to deploy from a specific revision in your repository that you check out.

It's really handy in cases like your example with two developers making a change to the same table.  Either the 2nd developer can pick up the change from the version control system before they commit their change.  Or you can use the branching/merging features of git to track these in separate branches and deploy them as separate changes.  There's scope to couple this into CI systems too.

Some specifics on running SQL Source Control with git:

- http://datachomp.com/archives/git-and-red-gate-sql-source-control/

And a link to a more general set-up guide

- http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/07/rocking-your-sql-source-control-world.html